# C++ socket client / server simple message sender

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new in the socket concept , when I tried to folow the tutorial , I can't folow this step

Tutorial :

```
sockaddr_in ip;
ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip.sin_port = htons(99999);
ip.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.2");
```

The problem is I can't folow the ip.sin_addr.saddr , when I type in :
ip.sin.addr. the only member this one have is s_un , what am I suppose to do ?

Comment: What library/tutorial are you using? Please add that to the question. What happens if you type ip.sin.addr->s_un? (Maybe addr is a pointer...)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, for example I have no idea where you are typing and why you expect anything to happen there. That said, ports are restricted to 16 bits, your port would need at least 17.

Comment: I don't think trying to connect to port `99999` is  good idea.The value for port needs to be not wider then 16bit.

Answer (score 1):

`ip.sin_addr` is an `in_addr` struct.  Depending on the platform you are coding for, `in_addr` has different members available.  For instance, on Linux, it has a single member:

```
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr;
};
```

Whereas on Windows, it has a `union` of three members:

```
struct in_addr {
    union {
        struct{
            unsigned char s_b1,
            s_b2,
            s_b3,
            s_b4;
        } S_un_b;
        struct {
            unsigned short s_w1,
            s_w2;
        } S_un_w;
        unsigned long S_addr;
    } S_un;
};
```

And then a precompiler `#define` macro maps `s_addr` to `S_un.S_addr`.

So, you can always use `ip.sin_addr.s_addr` in your code on all platforms, but it might resolve to different data members behind the scenes.

Comment: btw , is there a way to get the IP that PC I currently use ? , I add" 127.0.0.1" for testing , but if I run in WAN , is there a way to get the IP that I current use as Server and the other PC IP that I used as Client to send and receive message ?

Comment: To get a local IP, you have to use platform-specific APIs, such as  `getifaddrs()` on POSIX, or `GetAdaptersInfo()`/`GetAdaptersAddresses()` on Windows. To have a client get a server's IP to connect to, use `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the server's hostname via DNS.

Comment: sorry , but can you make a demo that cout the IP address in the console ?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of such functions floating around.  Such examples do not belong with this question. This question has been answered as asked.  If you want help getting local IPs, that needs to be posted as a new question.